# Django .exclude() returning unexpected results

Tags: django, django-queryset

Am I using this wrong?:

`qs = self.model.objects.exclude(invoice__sale_date__lt=date, id=instance.id)`

This returns items with an `invoice.sale_date` before the specified date.

This is my input:

```
print(date)
print("---")
qs = self.model.objects.exclude(invoice__sale_date__lt=date, id=instance.id)
for q in qs:
    print(q.invoice.sale_date)
```

and the output:

```
2015-05-01
---
2015-04-01
2015-05-01
```

If I remove the `id=instance.id` portion, the object with the earlier date is properly excluded. `instance` in this case, is an object whose `invoice.sale_date` defines the `date` value in this case, and I would also like it excluded. It seems like this is how it should work, according to [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#exclude), but maybe I am reading it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query you are executing means AND. That means that it will exclude sales_date less than date AND id is equal to instance.id.

If I understood it correctly, you can do it like this:

```
qs = self.model.objects.exclude(invoice__sale_date__lt=date).exclude(id=instance.id)
```

Comment: But that is what I want. I would like both the be excluded?

Comment: Ohhh! Thanks alot :)

Comment: If you will not change the query, it will only exclude object with `invoice__sale_date` less than date AND `id=instance.id`.  I think it's not really what you want.

Comment: ya ya. Light bulb went on. Much appreciated, sir.

Comment: @AdamStarrh it would be great to mark it as an answer. Just farming reputation. :D, thanks!

Comment: 4 more minutes and SO will let me give it to ya!